# Habilitar conteudo após uma data

Tags: php, javascript

Boa tarde, sou novo por aqui e também nesse universo de programação

Precisava fazer com que um link no meu site esteja disponível só depois de uma data.

EX: Link 1 so libera depois do dia 24/03/2018

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em php você pode fazer a verificação ao abrir a página:

```
<?php

//Data atual
$date = date('Y-m-d');

if($date >= suadata){
// não faz nada;
}else{

  //O die vai fazer o script morrer se a data for menor que a esperada
  die('Site não disponível, volte em "Sua data"');
}
?>

//Seu site dps
<html>...
```

//Você quer que o usuário defina uma data e então a partir dela a página irá ver se a data atual está de acordo, no exemplo usarei o Mysql, então vamos lá:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>For Business</title>

</head>
<body>

      <form method="POST" action="php/registra_data_no_db.php">
          //Procure algo para formatar essa data
          <input type="text" id="data" required="true">

        <button type="submit" >Cadastrar</button>

      </form>

 </body>
</html>
```

registra_data_no_db.php:

```
  <?php

  $mysqli = new mysqli("host", "user", "password", "db");

  $data = $_POST['data'];

  $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO suatabela VALUES (NULL,'id_da_pagina','$data')");

  ?>
```

Na sua página você usa o id da banco para saber qual página buscar

Então ao entrar na página você verifica:

```
  <?php

   $mysqli = new mysqli("host","user","password", "db");

   $date = date('Y-m-d');
   if($mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM suatabela where id_da_pagina='identificacao_da_sua_pagina' AND data >='$date'")){
   //Se existe então é verdadeiro, ou seja, não faz nada, só continua
   }else{
   //Caso não exista, o die morre o script
       die('Data indisponível');
   }


   //Sua página
   <html>....
```

Lembrando, esse exemplo é bem genérico, é somente para você ter uma ideia de como fazer, lógico que não irei deixar aqui exatamente tudo que você precisa, cabe a você implantar sua lógica. Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Woton, mas seria mais ou menos assim, estou trabalhando com Wordpress tenho uma lista com repetidor a qual o usuario coloca o nome de cada módulo do curso, porem não posso deixar todos os módulos abertos, então queria fazer a seguinte lógica

- O usuario define a data de liberação pelo wordpress 
- Se estiver antes da data o botão fica sem click agora se estiver na data certa o botão libera

Comment: @LukasCastro entedi, eu não entendo muito de wordpress, mas a lógica pra mim séria: criar um banco de dados que salve a data que seu usuário definiu e na página em questão ele busque o campo da minha resposta lá "suadata" do banco, eu vou modificar a resposta pra te mostrar com html e php puro, só um momento

Comment: Cara!! Você e 10!!! Me ajudou muito, Obrigado rodou liso aqui!

Comment: @LukasCastro fico feliz que resolveu, então gostaria que você marcasse a resposta como aceita, assim outras pessoas que tiverem o mesmo problema conseguissem resolve-lo, vlw, tenha uma otima tarde